Layer-specific learning rate (Tensorflow)
I'm trying to implement a simple DQN model with layer-specific learning rate. I'm using a sequential keras model with only two hidden and one output layer.
Unfortunately, the Tensorflow-addons package with the MultiOptimizer  wrapper doesn't work anymore. Is there another way to implement this?
